# Detecting Ellipses and Rectangles in Edge-Detected Image using OpenCV (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

In my situation, I discovered the edges of an object that resembles a rectangle and has a shape similar to a rectangle. Now, when I take away the rectangular object, the edge takes on an ellipse shape. I want to see if the object with the rectangle shape is there or not.

Description:

I have followed these steps to reach the current stage:

1. Loaded an image.
2. Applied edge detection (e.g., Canny) to the image to highlight the edges.
3. Obtained a binary edge-detected image.

Now, I need assistance with the next steps, which involve identifying and marking **ellipse **and **rectangle** within the edge-detected image. I'd like to:

Detect ellipse and rectangle within the image.
Draw bounding boxes or ellipses around these detected shapes.
Retrieve their coordinates, dimensions, and angles if applicable.

Now, I want to detect and mark ellipses and rectangles in the 'edges' image.
What's the best approach to achieve this?
Specific Questions:

What OpenCV functions or methods can I use to detect ellipses within the edge-detected image?
How can I draw bounding boxes or ellipses around the detected shapes?
How do I retrieve information about the detected shapes, such as coordinates, dimensions, and angles?

These are the Canny edge detected images.
[rectangle image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMWXB.jpg)
[oval image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ttgg.jpg)

I here by added the images marking the rectangle and ellipse shape. [rectangle marked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41RJA.png)
[ellipse marked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PEUA.png)

Any code examples or step-by-step guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand your question with respect to what you show in your images. I do not see any rectangle nor any oval in your images. Please mark what your want to extract

Comment: I have made the necessary changes please check the question and let me know if you have any queries @fmw42

Comment: See cv2.fitEllipse() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf259efaad93098103d6c27b9e4900ffa.